# ADODB connection to MYSQL 8.0

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I am using Windows 10, Excel 2016 and I'm trying to create an ADODB connection to a MYSQL80 instance on my laptop in Excel using VBA.

I get an error "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified."  I have tried this with both MYSQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver and MYSQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver.  Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'

I have both ODBC connections established and a test is successful on both.  Note they are 64bit versions as my OS is 64bit.

ODBC Connection

[image: 1]

My code includes

```
Public oSConn       As New ADODB.Connection

Public Function GetSQLConnectionString() As String

GetSQLConnectionString = "Driver ={MYSQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=hstest;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;"

End Function
```

and have tried with

```
GetSQLConnectionString = "Driver ={MYSQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=hstest;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;"
```

have also tried this excluding the port=3306

have also tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1

```
Sub UpLoadData()


oSConn.Open GetSQLConnectionString()

...

end sub
```

The error occurs when running the OSConn.Open line.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine found the answer.

GetSQLConnectionString = "Driver ={MYSQL ODBC 8.0 U

should be

GetSQLConnectionString = "Driver={MYSQL ODBC 8.0 U

note the removal of the space after the word Driver.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).